# Any tricks to stop flickering in between page transitions?

Tags: html, flicker, hta

Specifically, I am using a .hta to display pages. As the content is local, pages load instantly, but there is flicker as they redraw. Are there any tricks you can use to stop it flickering or reduce the effect?

I heard somewhere that page transition effects can help, but does anyone have any ideas? Keep in mind that as its a .hta file, I have more flexibility, and can run vbscript etc. and do fancy things.

Comment: I used to get flickering on all pages that linked in and out of pages with flash objects on them.

Comment: Used to? Did you fix it? :)  _ The pages have a big background that I think is half the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started bundling jquery in with my HTAs to use some of the UI cleanups, For instance loading the pages via ajax and showing a loading image, or slide transitions. This would also allow you to preload images, which may reduce flicker. Mind you preloading images is just as easy without jquery, you can even user css to load the big guys off screen, they should stay in the cache when you go to the next page.